# Grid component for tabular data on iOS

Tags: ios, components

I've got a couple apps that display tabular data in iOS. The easiest way to explain is probably with screenshots:

[image: MySQL Database Client][image: MTG Card Database]

As you can see, I'm just using HTML forums for displaying this data at the moment. What I'm looking for in a grid is the following:

- Dynamic Columns (add/remove columns on the fly)
- Static Header (column names are always visible at the top of the table even as you scroll down)
- Image support

Things that would be nice:
 + Column sorting

I've been looking for a library that would help me with this, but I cannot find anything around. I'm even willing to purchase a commercial library but I need to find one.

Does anyone know of any libraries that may support what I am looking for? Please note, this is for iOS and NOT for the Mac (otherwise I would just use NSTable).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Grid component from [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobigrids/)? Looks quite good.